# How to return both string and double in java

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

Hello I'm making a program that will print price of tickets.
I'm having a problem returning a string .

Here is my code

```
 public class DiscountTicket extends Ticket
 {
     private int numberDays;
     private int serial;
     public static double price;
     public static String s;

 public DiscountTicket(int serial, String t, int numberDays)
 {
    super(serial);
    this.numberDays = numberDays;
    s = t;
 }

 public double getPrice()
 {
    if (numberDays > 7)
    {
        price = 20.0;

    }
    else
    {
        price = 15.0;
    }

   return price ;
 }


}
```

If I return the string passed to my method. It will print that it's not compatible to convert a double to string. I tried to convert it and it just gave me a 0.0 output.

Comment: post your code to convert double to string

Comment: design issue, public static double price;  will always have the same value for all instances of class DiscountTicket. I guess you should drop the static here.

Comment: Not sure why you would want a number to a string, but you could try to do "return (string)price".

Comment: I used Double.toString and it passed 0.0

Comment: I want to output something like this
price : 20 type : (string)

Comment: you should change return type to String instead of double and you can do like that String k = String.valueOf(price);and return k;

Comment: I did that and it return 0.0 instead of 20.0 or 15.0

Comment: is it possible that you have getPrice Method in your Ticket class, so then you must override it with @Override, i guess thats why your if clause isnt processed, did you try debugging with a breakpoint?

Comment: @AngeloDayao,did you use String.valueOf(price)?when i test it,it return 10.0 value.

Answer (score 0):

In order to return multiple things, you can use an array of `Object`s. For example (I assume you want `getPrice()` to return `price` and `s`:

```
public Object[] getPrice() {
   if (numberDays > 7)
   {
       price = 20.0;
   }
   else
   {
       price = 15.0;
   }
   Object[] array = new Object[2];
   array[0] = price;
   array[1] = s;
   return array;
}
```

Then you can cast to Double and String after the array is returned.

Comment: Im using an abstract method btw. 

    public abstract class Ticket
    {
        private int serial;
 
        public Ticket(int serial)
        {
            this.serial = serial;
        }

        public abstract double getPrice();
 
        public String toString()
    {
       return "Ticket: [serial#  " + serial + " Price: " + getPrice() + "]" ;
   
        }
 

    }

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this Convert using

```
     DiscountTicket discountTicket = new DiscountTicket ();

     //This gives you a string value
     String stringValueOfDouble = String.valueOf(discountTicket.getPrice());
```

OR

String.format() is a new alternative that can be used for converting a Double to String object. It is first introduced in Java 5 (JDK1.5) and has many cool features.

Syntax

```
 public static String format(String format, Object... args)
```

There are many options on how to use this method. But for conversion purposes, here is a simple example:

Example

```
 double number = -895.25f;
 String numberAsString = String.format ("%f", number);
```

And the variable numberAsString will have the value "-895.250000"
We can also control the number of decimal places.

```
   double number = -895.25f;
   System.out.println(String.format ("%.1f", number));
   System.out.println(String.format ("%.2f", number));
   System.out.println(String.format ("%.3f", number));
```

Will display

```
 -895.3
 -895.25
 -895.250
```

[1]

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7t05Q.png
```

Comment: still the same prints 0.0

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DiscountTicket extends Ticket {

private int numberDays;
private int serial;
public static double price;
public static String s;

public DiscountTicket(int serial, String t, int numberDays) {
super(serial);
this.numberDays = numberDays;
s = t;
}

@Override
public double getPrice()
 {
    if (numberDays > 7)
    {
        price = 20.0;

    }
    else
    {
        price = 15.0;
    }

   return price ;
 }
```

}

```
public abstract class Ticket {
private int serial;

public Ticket(int serial) {
    this.serial = serial;
}

public abstract double getPrice();

public String toString() {
    return "Ticket: [serial# " + serial + " Price: " + getPrice() + "]";
}
}

  public class MainClass {

  public static void main(String args[]){

   DiscountTicket discountTicket = new DiscountTicket(5,"ashwani", 6);

    double d =  discountTicket.getPrice();

    String stringOfDouble = String.valueOf(d);



  }
}
```

And its working for me , check for other mistake you have